# Understanding the recursive fast Fourier Transform Algorithm from CLRS

Tags: algorithms, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Consider the following recursive fast Fourier transform algorithm from CLRS:

[image: CLRS: Recursive-FFT]

I believe that I understand this algorithm correctly: you split the input coefficients into the odd and even terms, recurse, and combine using the roots of unity.

However, I am aware that you can also use this recursive fast Fourier transform algorithm to evaluate polynomials at roots of unity modulo $n$ rather than just complex roots of unity over the set of complex numbers.

Given a coefficient vector $(8, -4, 2, 3, -5, -4, 2, 1)$, which represents $8 - 4x + 2x^2 + \cdots + x^7$, I want to evaluate the corresponding polynomial at eight $8^{\text{th}}$ complex roots of unity modulo $17$, which I know to be $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 15, 13$. Moreover, I want to do this with the fast Fourier transform described above. I think that if I am working over the integers modulo $17$, then I need to use $2$ as my primitive root of unity rather than $e^{2\pi i/n}$, but I can be wrong about this.

I will show you my work, and why I think it is incorrect.

Firstly, I recurse and divide the original problem into two subproblems:

$$(8, -4, 2, 3, -5, -4, 2, 1) \rightarrow^{\text{subproblems}} (8, 2, -5, 2) \text{ and } (-4, 3, -4, 1) $$

Next, I will solve the problem $(8, 2, -5, 2)$ by recursing:

$$(8, 2, -5, 2) \rightarrow^{\text{subproblems}} (8, -5) \text{ and } (2, 2).$$

Next, I will solve the subproblem $(8, -5)$ by combining the solutions of $(8)$ and $(-5)$, which are just $8$ and $-5$. I obtain $y_0 = 8 - 1 \cdot 5 = 3$ and $y_1 = 8 - 1 \cdot (-5) = 13$. In a similar manner: $(2, 2)$ returns $4$ and $0$. From here, I can solve combine these two solutions to solve $(8, 2, -5, 2)$ by computing $y_0 = 3 + 4 = 7$, $y_1 = 13 + 2 \cdot 0 = 13$, $y_2 = 3 - 4 \equiv 16$, and $y_3 = 13 - 2 \cdot 0 \equiv 13$. So we return $7, 13, -1, \text{ and } 13$.

I repeat the same procedure on $(-4, 3, -4, 1)$, for which I omit steps, but I will post them upon request. We find this call returns $(4, 12, 13, 4)$.

Finally, I combine for the final solution and I get $y_0 = 4 + 7 = 11, y_1 = 13 + 2 \cdot 12 \equiv 3, y_2 = 16 + 4 \cdot 13 \equiv y_3 = 13 + 8 \cdot 4 \equiv 11, y_4 = 7 - 4 \equiv 3, y_5 = 13 - 2 \cdot 12 \equiv 6, y_6 = 16 - 4\cdot 13 \equiv 15, \text{ and } y_7 = 13 - 8 \cdot 4 \equiv 15$.

But when I plug in the roots of unity manually into this polynomial through Wolfram Alpha, I get different answers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a calculation error: whereas $(8,2,-5,2) \to (7,13,16,13)$ is fine, you should be getting $(4,3,-4,1) \to (4,16,13,0)$.

Comment: Note also that your polynomial is $8+4x+\cdots$, not $8-4x+\cdots$.

Comment: Hey @YuvalFilmus. Actually, the polynomial was correct, and I copied down the coefficient vector wrong. It should have been $(-4, 3, -4, 1) \rightarrow (4, 16, 13, 0).$ I just updated my post. Hopefully it makes more sense. Could you please check again if it is okay?

Comment: Yes, that's also what I get. You should update your post with the corrected numbers. Don't add a new section titled "EDIT" – just fix the current numbers in you post which are wrong.